# Convert one record into form of two column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my old Stored Proceder result returned in form of counts . it returned as below. Result is correct but now I want this row result in form of table. 
Please look into this and help me.

Result in form of Row:

```
SELECT 100 AS A ,200 AS B ,300 AS C
```

Required Result in form of column:

```
TextKey  |  TextValue
---------------------
   A           100
   B           200 
   C           300
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest would be to use a `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT 'A' AS TextKey, 100 AS TextValue UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 200 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 300
```

Comment: +1 for @muhmud and +1 for Lieven Keersmaekers for diefferent answers. But UNION ALL is Clear one, Fast and Easy to use...

Answer (score 2):

```
select TextKey, TextValue
from (
    SELECT 100 AS A ,200 AS B ,300 AS C
) t unpivot (TextValue for TextKey in ([A], [B], [C])) tp
```

Comment: +1 for muhmud and +1 for @Lieven Keersmaekers for diefferent answers. But UNION ALL is Clear one, Fast and Easy to use...

Answer (score 1):

Query:
**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12875)**

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM (VALUES ('A', 100), 
             ('B', 200), 
             ('C', 300)) as a(TextKey, TextValue)
```

Result:

```
| TEXTKEY | TEXTVALUE |
-----------------------
|       A |       100 |
|       B |       200 |
|       C |       300 |
```

Comment: +1 If OP is using SQL Server 2008 or up, this would be the easiest to adjust for additional elements.