# Combine multiple rows into single row with separate columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm having the following table structure and the expected output is listed below how to achieve the result

```
id -  date -   score 
1  - 2013/04/13 - 100
2  - 2013/04/14 - 92 
3  - 2013/04/15 - 33
```

Expected output :

```
date -2013-04-13 - 2013-04-14 -  2013-04-15 
score -  100      -   92        -    33
```

Comment: are you looking for a way to transpose a table view? Here are some examples at codeproject http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/318546/Transpose-Rows-in-SQL-Server

Comment: yes i want to transpose the table view

Comment: it need to happen dynamically with that "id" field

Comment: Please refer this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233232/convert-one-record-into-form-of-two-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [**`PIVOT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT date, score FROM tablename) AS t
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Score)
  FOR date IN([2013-04-13], [2013-04-14], [2013-04-15])
) AS p;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46c1a/1)

This will give you:

```
| 2013-04-13 | 2013-04-14 | 2013-04-15 |
----------------------------------------
|        100 |         92 |         33 |
```

---

If you want to do this dynamically, you have to use dynamic sql to do so. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(date)
                      FROM tablename
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SET @query = 'SELECT *
              FROM (SELECT date, score FROM tablename) AS t
              PIVOT
              (
                MAX(Score)
                FOR date IN( ' + @cols+ ' )
              ) AS p;';


EXECUTE(@query);
```

See it in action here:

- [**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46c1a/5)

**Note that:** I am assuming that you have unique dates entries in your table, in this case the `MAX(score)` will work fine, in case there is more dates entries for the same day you can use `SUM` instead. But, you have to use any aggregate function with the `PIVOT` table operator.

Comment: Thank you mahmoud it helped a lot for me